# Calendar booking

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I use script for booking and is work perfect but i dont know how to make some changes. Booking script have three files:

Over File calendar.php see calendar. I click on the day and I get free time to book.

I made that can be booked at least two slots and up to 4 but can not do to the reserved slots must be next to each other in order to reserve terms of half an hour or an hour continuously.

Example: i want reserved minimal 1 hour and max 2 hour continuously.

Can you help me to resolve this problem?

Second problem is name of day and months:

I tried despite all this change the names of days and months in the Spanish but I never could. Do you have a solution for this?

Now the names of days and months are displayed in English.

Calendar.php script is:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

include('php/connect.php'); 
include('classes/class_calendar.php');

$calendar = new booking_diary($link);

if(isset($_GET['month'])) $month = $_GET['month']; else $month = date("m");
if(isset($_GET['year'])) $year = $_GET['year']; else $year = date("Y");
if(isset($_GET['day'])) $day = $_GET['day']; else $day = 0;


// Unix Timestamp of the date a user has clicked on
$selected_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 01, $year); 

// Unix Timestamp of the previous month which is used to give the back arrow the correct month and year 
$back = strtotime("-1 month", $selected_date); 

// Unix Timestamp of the next month which is used to give the forward arrow the correct month and year 
$forward = strtotime("+1 month", $selected_date);

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Calendar</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var check_array = [];

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".fields").click(function(){

        dataval = $(this).data('val');

        // Show the Selected Slots box if someone selects a slot
        if($("#outer_basket").css("display") == 'none') { 
            $("#outer_basket").css("display", "block");
        }

        if(jQuery.inArray(dataval, check_array) == -1) {
            check_array.push(dataval);
        } else {
            // Remove clicked value from the array
            check_array.splice($.inArray(dataval, check_array) ,1); 
        }

        slots=''; hidden=''; basket = 0;

        cost_per_slot = $("#cost_per_slot").val();
        //cost_per_slot = parseFloat(cost_per_slot).toFixed(2)

        for (i=0; i< check_array.length; i++) {
            slots += check_array[i] + '\r\n';
            hidden += check_array[i].substring(0, 8) + '|';
            basket = (basket + parseFloat(cost_per_slot));
        }

        // Populate the Selected Slots section
        $("#selected_slots").html(slots);

        // Update hidden slots_booked form element with booked slots
        $("#slots_booked").val(hidden);     

        // Update basket total box
        basket = basket.toFixed(2);
        $("#total").html(basket);   

        // Hide the basket section if a user un-checks all the slots
        if(check_array.length < 2)
        $("#outer_basket").css("display", "none");
        if(check_array.length > 4)
        $("#outer_basket").css("display", "none");

    });


    $(".classname").click(function(){

        msg = '';

        if($("#name").val() == '')
        msg += 'Please enter a Name\r\n';

        if($("#email").val() == '')
        msg += 'Please enter an Email address\r\n';

        if($("#phone").val() == '')
        msg += 'Please enter a Phone number\r\n';   

        if(msg != '') {
            alert(msg);
            return false;
        }

    });

    // Firefox caches the checkbox state.  This resets all checkboxes on each page load 
    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

});




</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php     

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $calendar->after_post($month, $day, $year);  
}   

// Call calendar function
$calendar->make_calendar($selected_date, $back, $forward, $day, $month, $year);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Script book_slots.php is:

```
<?php

include('php/connect.php'); 

if(isset($_POST['slots_booked'])) $slots_booked = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['slots_booked']);
if(isset($_POST['name'])) $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
if(isset($_POST['email'])) $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
if(isset($_POST['phone'])) $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['phone']);
if(isset($_POST['booking_date'])) $booking_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['booking_date']);
if(isset($_POST['cost_per_slot'])) $cost_per_slot = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['cost_per_slot']);


$booking_array = array(
    "slots_booked" => $slots_booked,    
    "booking_date" => $booking_date,
    "cost_per_slot" => number_format($cost_per_slot, 2),
    "name" => $name,
    "email" => $email,
    "phone" => $phone
);

$explode = explode('|', $slots_booked);

foreach($explode as $slot) {

    if(strlen($slot) > 0) {

        $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO bookings (date, start, name, email, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); 
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $booking_date, $slot, $name, $email, $phone);
        $stmt->execute();

    } // Close if

} // Close foreach

print_r('<pre>');
print_r($booking_array);
print_r('</pre>');

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Booking Confirmed</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class='success'>The booking has been made into the database.</div>

<p style='font-family:courier; font-size:13px; margin-top:25px'>
The booking has been inserted into the database.<br>
The array above shows you details of the $_POST.<br>
</p>

<p style='font-family:courier; font-size:13px; margin-top:25px'>
You might want to use this page to: 
</p>

<ul style='font-family:courier; font-size:13px'>
    <li>Redirect the user to a payment gateway (Paypal)</li>
    <li>Simply show a confirmation page</li>
    <li>Integrate with your basket</li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

And class_calendar.php is:

```
<?php


class booking_diary {


// Mysqli connection
function __construct($link) {
    $this->link = $link;    
}

// Settings you can change:


// Time Related Variables
public $booking_start_time          = "09:30";          // The time of the first slot in 24 hour H:M format  
public $booking_end_time            = "19:00";          // The time of the last slot in 24 hour H:M format  
public $booking_frequency           = 30;               // The slot frequency per hour, expressed in minutes.   

// Day Related Variables

public $day_format                  = 1;                // Day format of the table header.  Possible values (1, 2, 3)   
                                                            // 1 = Show First digit, eg: "M"
                                                            // 2 = Show First 3 letters, eg: "Mon"
                                                            // 3 = Full Day, eg: "Monday"

public $day_closed                  = array("Saturday", "Sunday");  // If you don't want any 'closed' days, remove the day so it becomes: = array();

public $day_closed_text             = "CLOSED";         // If you don't want any any 'closed' remove the text so it becomes: = "";

// Cost Related Variables
public $cost_per_slot               = 20.50;            // The cost per slot
public $cost_currency_tag           = "&pound;";        // The currency tag in HTML such as &euro; &pound; &yen;


//  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE

public $day_order                   = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");



public $day, $month, $year, $selected_date, $back, $back_month, $back_year, $forward, $forward_month, $forward_year, $bookings, $count, $days, $is_slot_booked_today;


/*========================================================================================================================================================*/


function make_calendar($selected_date, $back, $forward, $day, $month, $year) {

    // $day, $month and $year are the $_GET variables in the URL
    $this->day = $day;    
    $this->month = $month;
    $this->year = $year;

    // $back and $forward are Unix Timestamps of the previous / next month, used to give the back arrow the correct month and year 
    $this->selected_date = $selected_date;       
    $this->back = $back;
    $this->back_month = date("m", $back);
    $this->back_year = date("Y", $back); // Minus one month back arrow

    $this->forward = $forward;
    $this->forward_month = date("m", $forward);
    $this->forward_year = date("Y", $forward); // Add one month forward arrow    

    // Make the booking array
    $this->make_booking_array($year, $month);

}


function make_booking_array($year, $month, $j = 0) { 

    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("SELECT name, date, start FROM bookings WHERE date LIKE  CONCAT(?, '-', ?, '%')"); 
    $this->is_slot_booked_today = 0; // Defaults to 0

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $year, $month); 
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $date, $start);   
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    while($stmt->fetch()) {    

        $this->bookings_per_day[$date][] = $start;

        $this->bookings[] = array(
            "name" => $name, 
            "date" => $date, 
            "start" => $start        
        ); 

        // Used by the 'booking_form' function later to check whether there are any booked slots on the selected day        
        if($date == $this->year . '-' . $this->month . '-' . $this->day) {
            $this->is_slot_booked_today = 1;
        } 

    }

    // Calculate how many slots there are per day
    $this->slots_per_day = 0;   
    for($i = strtotime($this->booking_start_time); $i<= strtotime($this->booking_end_time); $i = $i + $this->booking_frequency * 60) {
        $this->slots_per_day ++;
    }   

    $stmt->close();     
    $this->make_days_array($year, $month);    

} // Close function


function make_days_array($year, $month) { 

    // Calculate the number of days in the selected month                 
    $num_days_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year); 

    // Make $this->days array containing the Day Number and Day Number in the selected month       

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_days_month; $i++) { 

        // Work out the Day Name ( Monday, Tuesday... ) from the $month and $year variables
        $d = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $i, $year); 

        // Create the array

        $this->days[] = array("daynumber" => $i, "dayname" => date("l", $d)); 

        //$this->days[0] = array("daynumber" => 0, "dayname" => ("Ponedeljak"));
        //$this->days[1] = array("daynumber" => 1, "dayname" => ("Utorak"));
        //$this->days[2] = array("daynumber" => 2, "dayname" => ("Sreda"));
        //$this->days[3] = array("daynumber" => 3, "dayname" => ("Cetvrtak"));
        //$this->days[4] = array("daynumber" => 4, "dayname" => ("Petak"));
        //$this->days[5] = array("daynumber" => 5, "dayname" => ("Subota"));
        //$this->days[6] = array("daynumber" => 6, "dayname" => ("Nedelja")); 



    //$this->days array:

    //[0] => Array
    //    (
    //        [daynumber] => 1
   //         [dayname] => Monday
    //    )

    //[1] => Array
     //   (
     //       [daynumber] => 2
     //       [dayname] => Tuesday
     //   )

    } 
    $this->make_blank_start($year, $month);
    $this->make_blank_end($year, $month);   

} // Close function


function make_blank_start($year, $month) {

    /*
    Calendar months start on different days
    Therefore there are often blank 'unavailable' days at the beginning of the month which are showed as a grey block
    The code below creates the blank days at the beginning of the month
    */  

    // Get first record of the days array which will be the First Day in the month ( eg Wednesday )
    $first_day = $this->days[0]['dayname']; $s = 0;

        // Loop through $day_order array ( Monday, Tuesday ... )
        foreach($this->day_order as $i => $r) {

            // Compare the $first_day to the Day Order
            if($first_day == $r && $s == 0) {

                $s = 1;  // Set flag to 1 stop further processing

            } elseif($s == 0) {

                $blank = array(
                    "daynumber" => 'blank',
                    "dayname" => 'blank'
                );

                // Prepend elements to the beginning of the $day array
                array_unshift($this->days, $blank);
            }

    } // Close foreach  

} // Close function


function make_blank_end($year, $month) {

    /*
    Calendar months start on different days
    Therefore there are often blank 'unavailable' days at the end of the month which are showed as a grey block
    The code below creates the blank days at the end of the month
    */

    // Add blank elements to end of array if required.
    $pad_end = 7 - (count($this->days) % 7);

    if ($pad_end < 7) {

        $blank = array(
            "daynumber" => 'blank',
            "dayname" => 'blank'
        );

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pad_end; $i++) {                            
            array_push($this->days, $blank);
        }

    } // Close if

    $this->calendar_top(); 

} // Close function


function calendar_top() {

    // This function creates the top of the table containg the date and the forward and back arrows 

    echo "
    <div id='lhs'><div id='outer_calendar'>

    <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' id='calendar'>
        <tr id='week'>
        <td align='left'><a href='?month=" . date("m", $this->back) . "&amp;year=" . date("Y", $this->back) . "'>&laquo;</a></td>
        <td colspan='5' id='center_date'>" . date("F, Y", $this->selected_date) . "</td>    
        <td align='right'><a href='?month=" . date("m", $this->forward) . "&amp;year=" . date("Y", $this->forward) . "'>&raquo;</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>";

    /*
    Make the table header with the appropriate day of the week using the $day_format variable as user defined above
    Definition:

        1: Show First digit, eg: "M"
        2: Show First 3 letters, eg: "Mon"
        3: Full Day, eg: "Monday"       

    */

    foreach($this->day_order as $r) {


        switch($this->day_format) {

            case(1):    
                echo "<th>" . substr($r, 0, 1) . "</th>";                   
            break;

            case(2):
                echo "<th>" . substr($r, 0, 3) . "</th>";           
            break;

            case(3):    
                echo "<th>" . $r . "</th>";
            break;

        } 
           // Close switch

    } // Close foreach


    echo "</tr>";   

    $this->make_cells();

} // Close function


function make_cells($table = '') {

    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($this->days as $i => $r) { // Loop through the date array

        $j = $i + 1; $tag = 0;          

        // If the the current day is found in the day_closed array, bookings are not allowed on this day  
        if(in_array($r['dayname'], $this->day_closed)) {            
            echo "\r\n<td width='21' valign='top' class='closed'>" . $this->day_closed_text . "</td>";      
            $tag = 1;
        }


        // Past days are greyed out
        if (mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->month, sprintf("%02s", $r['daynumber']) + 1, $this->year) < strtotime("now") && $tag != 1) {     

            echo "\r\n<td width='21' valign='top' class='past'>";           
                // Output day number 
                if($r['daynumber'] != 'blank') echo $r['daynumber']; 

            echo "</td>";       
            $tag = 1;
        }


        // If the element is set as 'blank', insert blank day
        if($r['dayname'] == 'blank' && $tag != 1) {     
            echo "\r\n<td width='21' valign='top' class='unavailable'></td>";   
            $tag = 1;
        }


        // Now check the booking array $this->booking to see whether we have a booking on this day              
        $current_day = $this->year . '-' . $this->month . '-' . sprintf("%02s", $r['daynumber']);

        if(isset($this->bookings_per_day[$current_day]) && $tag == 0) {

            $current_day_slots_booked = count($this->bookings_per_day[$current_day]);

                if($current_day_slots_booked < $this->slots_per_day) {

                    echo "\r\n<td width='21' valign='top'>
                    <a href='calendar.php?month=" .  $this->month . "&amp;year=" .  $this->year . "&amp;day=" . sprintf("%02s", $r['daynumber']) . "' class='part_booked' title='This day is part booked'>" . 
                    $r['daynumber'] . "</a></td>"; 
                    $tag = 1;

                } else {

                    echo "\r\n<td width='21' valign='top'>
                    <a href='calendar.php?month=" .  $this->month . "&amp;year=" .  $this->year . "&amp;day=" . sprintf("%02s", $r['daynumber']) . "' class='fully_booked' title='This day is fully booked'>" . 
                    $r['daynumber'] . "</a></td>"; 
                    $tag = 1;           

                } // Close else 

        } // Close if


        if($tag == 0) {

            echo "\r\n<td width='21' valign='top'>
            <a href='calendar.php?month=" .  $this->month . "&amp;year=" .  $this->year . "&amp;day=" . sprintf("%02s", $r['daynumber']) . "' class='green' title='Please click to view bookings'>" . 
            $r['daynumber'] . "</a></td>";          

        }

        // The modulus function below ($j % 7 == 0) adds a <tr> tag to every seventh cell + 1;
            if($j % 7 == 0 && $i >1) {
            echo "\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>"; // Use modulus to give us a <tr> after every seven <td> cells
        }       

    }       

    echo "</tr></table></div><!-- Close outer_calendar DIV -->";

    if(isset($_GET['year']))
    $this->basket();

    echo "</div><!-- Close LHS DIV -->";

    // Check booked slots for selected date and only show the booking form if there are available slots 
    $current_day = $this->year . '-' . $this->month . '-' . $this->day; 
    $slots_selected_day = 0;

    if(isset($this->bookings_per_day[$current_day]))
    $slots_selected_day = count($this->bookings_per_day[$current_day]);

    if($this->day != 0 && $slots_selected_day < $this->slots_per_day) { 
        $this->booking_form();
    }


} // Close function


function booking_form() {

    echo "
    <div id='outer_booking'><h2>Available Slots</h2>

    <p>
    The following slots are available on <span> " . $this->day . "." . $this->month . "." . $this->year . "</span>
    </p>

    <table width='400' border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' id='booking'>
        <tr>
            <th width='150' align='left'>Start</th>
            <th width='150' align='left'>End</th>
            <th width='150' align='left'>Price</th>
            <th width='20' align='left'>Book</th>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>";


        // Create $slots array of the booking times
        for($i = strtotime($this->booking_start_time); $i<= strtotime($this->booking_end_time); $i = $i + $this->booking_frequency * 60) {
            $slots[] = date("H:i:s", $i);  
        }           


        // Loop through $this->bookings array and remove any previously booked slots

        if($this->is_slot_booked_today == 1) { // $this->is_slot_booked_today created in function 'make_booking_array'

            foreach($this->bookings as $i => $b) { 

                if($b['date'] == $this->year . '-' . $this->month . '-' . $this->day) {

                    // Remove any booked slots from the $slots array
                    $slots = array_diff($slots, array($b['start']));

                } // Close if

            } // Close foreach

        } // Close if



        // Loop through the $slots array and create the booking table

        foreach($slots as $i => $start) {           

            // Calculate finish time
            $finish_time = strtotime($start) + $this->booking_frequency * 60; 

            echo "
            <tr>\r\n
                <td>" . $start . "</td>\r\n
                <td>" . date("H:i:s", $finish_time) . "</td>\r\n
                <td>" . $this->cost_currency_tag . number_format($this->cost_per_slot, 2) . "</td>\r\n
                <td width='110'><input data-val='" . $start . " - " . date("H:i:s", $finish_time) . "' class='fields' type='checkbox'></td>
            </tr>";

        } // Close foreach          

        echo "</table></div><!-- Close outer_booking DIV -->";


} // Close function


function basket($selected_day = '') {

    if(!isset($_GET['day']))
    $day = '01';
    else
    $day = $_GET['day'];    

    // Validate GET date values
    if(checkdate($_GET['month'], $day, $_GET['year']) !== false) {
        $selected_day = $_GET['year'] . '-' . $_GET['month'] . '-' . $day;  
    } else { 
        echo 'Invalid date!';
        exit();
    }

    echo "<div id='outer_basket'>

    <h2>Rezervi&#353;i termin za " . $this->day . "." . $this->month . "." . $this->year . "</h2>

        <div id='selected_slots'></div>     

            <div id='basket_details'>

                <form method='post' action='book_slots.php'>

                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input name='name' id='name' type='text' class='text_box'>

                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input name='email' id='email' type='text' class='text_box'>    

                    <label>Phone</label>
                    <input name='phone' id='phone' type='text' class='text_box'>    

                        <div id='outer_price'>
                            <div id='currency'>" . $this->cost_currency_tag . "</div>
                            <div id='total'></div>
                        </div>                                  

                    <input type='hidden' name='slots_booked' id='slots_booked'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='cost_per_slot' id='cost_per_slot' value='" . $this->cost_per_slot . "'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='booking_date' value='" . $day . '.' . $_GET['month'] . '.' . $_GET['year'] . "'>

                    <input type='submit' class='classname' value='Make Booking'>

                </form>

            </div><!-- Close basket_details DIV -->

    </div><!-- Close outer_basket DIV -->";

} // Close function


} // Close Class

?>
```

Comment: Pay someone twenty bucks to sort thru this wall of code?

Comment: If i have money i not send script here. Thanks for your help.